# How can I use 'firebase login:ci' on a build server

Tags: node.js, firebase, github, firebase-cli

I am running a nodejs build using [Github Workflows](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/configuring-a-workflow) and I want to be able to build my project and then immediately deploy it to my firebase project. Using firebase deploy. But if I want to use the firebase-tools I have to login on the build server. But there isn't a way to get authenticated via email and password etc. Is there anyway to enable me to get what I want to accomplish done? [firebase-tools](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools#commands) Inside my build script is **"react-scripts build && firebase deploy"**

---

This is my workflow file, nodejs.yml:

---

```
name: Node CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

runs-on: ubuntu-latest

strategy:
  matrix:
    node-version: [8.x, 10.x, 12.x]

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v1
- name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
  uses: actions/setup-node@v1
  with:
    node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
- name: npm install, build, and test
  run: |
    npm i -g firebase-tools
    firebase login
    npm ci
    npm run build --if-present
    npm test
  env:
    CI: true
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You don't have to use `firebase login` on the CI system.  All you have to do is follow the [instructions in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#cli-ci-systems) to integrate with any CI system.

> **Use the CLI with CI systems**
>
> The Firebase CLI requires a browser to complete authentication, but
>   the CLI is fully compatible with CI and other headless environments.
>
> 1. On a machine with a browser, install the Firebase CLI.
> 2. Start the signin process by running the following command:
> 3. firebase login:ci
> 4. Visit the URL provided, then sign in using a Google account.
> 5. Print a new refresh token. The current CLI session will not be affected.
> 6. Store the output token in a secure but accessible way in your CI system.
> 7. Use this token when running firebase commands. You can use either of the following two options:
>
>    - Store the token as the environment variable FIREBASE_TOKEN. Your system will automatically use the token.
>    - Run all firebase commands with the --token  flag in your CI system. The order of precedence for token loading is flag,
>        environment variable, desired Firebase project.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast response. This helped so much and my builds are green now.

Comment: I didn't understand what does it mean by 
"Print a new refresh token. The current CLI session will not be affected."

I have auth code from the response
`
http://localhost:9005/?state=750916524&code=myauthcodeconfiscated&scope=email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20openid%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform&authuser=0&prompt=consent
`
Giving the code is giving authentication errors.

Comment: I was also a bit confused by the instruction "Print a new refresh token", but check the terminal output after following the instructions until step 4. It states "Success! Use this token to login on a CI server: ...".