# How to Run & Connect to Emulators with Cypress CI on GitHub Actions?

Tags: firebase, continuous-integration, cypress, github-actions, firebase-tools

I am trying to run e2e Cypress tests on Github actions. I build functions, run an emulator and start cypress like to:
`npx nx build functions | firebase emulators:start | nx e2e frontend-e2e --watch`

This works well on localhost, but fails on GitHub Actions, when the first part of the code tries to connect to the emulators.

```js
  cy.request(
    "DELETE",
    "http://localhost:9099/emulator/v1/projects/****/accounts"
  );
```

It can't reach the emulator on port `localhost:9099`, as I would normally do on localhost.

```
  1) Login
       runs setup:
     CypressError: `cy.request()` failed trying to load:

http://localhost:9099/emulator/v1/projects/****/accounts

We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.
```

Is there something I need to do about **connecting to localhost port on GitHub Actions**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! The Firebase emulator was throwing an error, but I haven't seen it because I ran it on one line with other commands: `npx nx build functions | firebase emulators:start | nx e2e frontend-e2e --watch`

I rewrote the job in the workflow:

```
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          browser: chrome
          build: npm run integration:build
          start: |
            npm run integration:emulate
            npm run integration:test
```

Calling custom scripts from `package.json` like so:

```
    "integration:build": "nx build functions && nx run frontend:build",
    "integration:emulate": "firebase use default && firebase emulators:start",
    "integration:test": "nx e2e frontend-e2e --watch",
```

Then I could see the Firebase error in the log and fixed them. There were two issues:

1. Selecting a project before running the emulators (adding `firebase use default`)
2. Firebase login ([great answer from the Firebase team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58848164/how-can-i-use-firebase-loginci-on-a-build-server))

After that, the emulators worked just as on localhost